# Python while loop does not continue

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, while-loop, pycharm

The program should keep asking the user to enter title and review while the answer for "Do you want to continue(Y/N)?" is Y. Instead it ask the user only once. Can someone help me figure out while the loop does not continue . Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():

 listOfReviews = obtainListOfReviews()
 displayResults(listOfReviews)

def obtainListOfReviews():
 listOfReviews = []
 carryOn ='Y'
 while carryOn =='Y':
  title = raw_input("Enter title:")
  review = int(input("Enter review:"))

  st = MovieReview(title, review)
  listOfReviews.append(st)
  carryOn = raw_input("Do you want to continue?(Y/N)? ")
  carryOn = carryOn.upper()
  return listOfReviews

def displayResults(listOfReviews):
     for r in listOfReviews:
         print(r)

class MovieReview:
 def __init__(self, title = " ", review = 0):
  self._title = title
  self._review = review
 def setTitle(self, title):
  self._title = title
 def setReview(self, review):
  self._review = review
 def getTitle(self):
  return self._title
 def getReview(self):
  return self._review
 def __str__(self):
  return ("Title: " + str(self._title) + " \nreview: " + str(self._review))
main()
```

Comment: Because you have `return` in the while loop

Comment: Your `return` is part of the `while` loop. Unindent it.

Comment: `return listOfReviews` causes the function `obtainListOfReviews()` to return the values stored in `listOfReviews` to be assigned to the variable `listOfReviews` in `main()`.

Comment: If you used a decent indentation level, instead of a single space, the issue might be more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong indentation for you line "return listOfReviews" :

```
def obtainListOfReviews():
 listOfReviews = []
 carryOn ='Y'
 while carryOn =='Y':
  title = raw_input("Enter title:")
  review = int(input("Enter review:"))

  st = MovieReview(title, review)
  listOfReviews.append(st)
  carryOn = raw_input("Do you want to continue?(Y/N)? ")
  carryOn = carryOn.upper()

 # Correct indentation
 return listOfReviews
```